# Properly align/center bootstrap3 image

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-position

In `container-fluid` I have row examples with some data I want to display, on top of mine text I will put an `img`. This is a standard section web-pages have these days.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <!-- SOCIETE row of columns -->
  <div class="row SOC-columns">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <img src='http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-1994-02-c-thumb.jpg' class=" img-rounded img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
        <h4><strong>No Broker or Hidden Fees</strong></h4>
      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img src='http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-2003-28-a-thumb.jpg' class=" img-rounded img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
        <h4><strong>Extremely Fast.</strong></h4>
      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
   </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img src='http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-2010-26-a-thumb.jpg' class=" img-rounded img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
        <h4><strong>Flexible Lease Terms</strong></h4>
      <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <hr>

  <div class="row SOC-columns">
    <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <img src='http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-1994-02-c-thumb.jpg' class=" img-rounded img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
        <h4><strong>Operations and Engeneering.</strong></h4>
      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img src='http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-2010-26-a-thumb.jpg' class=" img-rounded img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
        <h4><strong>Networking.</strong></h4>
      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
   </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img src='http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-2003-28-a-thumb.jpg' class=" img-rounded img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
        <h4><strong>Safety.</strong></h4>
      <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Now mine question is related to `img` positioning inside mine `columns`. I want to `center` images, and I'm doing that with

```
.SOC-columns img {
    padding-left: 220px;
}
```

in mine [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/copser/s9exw4gb/2/) example, and they are aligned. I assume that this is not the right way of positioning in my case or any case, I hope that someone can explain to me the right way of doing this.

Comment: `margin: 0 auto; ` to `.SOC-columns img` is best option as you applied `img-responsive` to your images and it's mentioned as `display: block;` and `width: 100%`. Otherwise `text-align: center` would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the:

```
.SOC-columns img {
    padding-left: 220px;
}
```

with:

```
.SOC-columns img {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Ok, so this is the proper way of aligning `img` inside `column`, is there more to it?

Comment: That's the extent of it. It's not super-proper, but it's widely accepted as the easiest and most reliable way to center an element inside of its parent.

Comment: That seems legit, I hope someone can elaborate on this matter, will accept you answer.

Answer (score 1):

According `.SOC-columns` has a `text-align: center` attribute, you can just add a `display: inline` attribute to your images.

```
.SOC-columns {
    text-align: center;
}

.SOC-columns img {
    display: inline;
}
```